Ищу компонент для visual studio
По воле случая, на время, попал в руки старый ноутбук. На котором установлена visual studio 2012 professional. Где я обнаружил возможность создавать в пару кликов проекты wpf на c++.

Хотелось бы подольше это пощупать. Поэтому пытаюсь у себя на ПК настроить visual studio 2019. Может быть из-за того, что у меня community версия у меня не получается? Пробовал устанавливать в visual studio installer все компоненты связанные с C++, но при запуске ide нет искомого типа проекта.
И если кому тоже стало интересно - доп. скрины:




Похоже эта ide уже не поддерживается. Ещё одна причина найти более новое решение.


Это не WPF, а UWP, не на С++, а на С++/CX. С++/CX действительно был объявлен устаревшим и вместо него для приложений UWP Microsoft рекомендует использовать обычный C++ c C++/WinRT. И да, вместо VS2019 стоит использовать VS2022.

Да, действительно. Попробовал создать UWP проект, и там всё похоже. Я выбрал VS2019, так как надеялся на связь поколений. Т.е. меньше отличий. Спасибо за ответ. Сейчас помечу вопрос как решённый.

"Вы сможете принять свой ответ через 2 дня" - а нет. Не смогу пока)

Недостаточно глубоко копнул.
Если бы помимо установки дополнительных компонентов, ещё попробовал с их помощью создавать проекты, то заметил бы общность с UWP.
Хорошо, что здесь подсказали.
